# IIS 7 Virtual Directory running PHP problem?

Tags: php, iis-7

I have recently setup a site on IIS 7 Windows 2008 Server, with PHP FastCGI. This site was run previously on IIS 6 Windows 2003 server, and it ran without any problems, now however PHP pages within the virtual directory I get a 500 - Internal server error. Within the Virtual directory html pages come up no problem. PhP pages outside of the virtual directory under the main domain directory serve up fine.

Anyone have any idea why this is an issue? I have also tried converting the virtual directory to an application, and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with IIS7 and the latest PHP, but previous versions of PHP would not run a web site outside of the c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ hierarchy. Try putting your web site in a directory under wwwroot; it should work.

This does seem to be a problem with PHP, specifically, and its relationship with IIS.

Comment: IIS lets you specify where the site being run is located, and php works fine.. Again, this is a virtual directory/application issue only.